# The image of an injective function whose domain is a topological space also a topology

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $(X, T )$ be a topological space, and let $f : X → Y$ be an injective (but not necessarily surjective) function.

QUESTIONS.

(1) Is $T_f := \{ f(U) : U ∈ T \}$ necessarily a topology on $Y$ ?

(2) Is it necessarily a topology on the range of $f$?

I would appreciate if someone could provide feedback and suggestions on my attempt. $T_f$ is not necessarily a topology on Y, for instance consider h:$\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ $h(x)=e^x$. Then The space $(Y,T_f)$ is not a topology since it does not contain Y (misses zero and all of the negative reals) 
But I think $T_f$ will be a topology on the range of f since 1. It contains the empty set, 2.It contains range f by definition. 3. It is closed under finite intersections because T is closed under inite intersections and since f is injective $f(\cap_{\alpha \in I} U)$ will be contained in $T_f$ and similarly for unions. 
Do I have the right idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to (1) is no.  Your example works fine, but you can generalize. If $f$ is any non-surjective function, then $Y\notin T_f$, so $T_f$ is not a topology on $Y$.

To prove (2), you just need to verify the axioms for a topology, one by one. One thing that will be useful is that since $f$ is injective, it commutes across union and intersection (these are simply set operations, and $f$ just relabeling elements in $X$ with elements in $Y$).

Comment: Thank you and your edit made things so much clearer too, cheers :)